# dbt power user visual studio code extension : features stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-code, dbt

[image]I recently installed the dbt power user extension and followed the configuration instructions, which included adding

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.sql": "jinja-sql"
    }
```

, and making the Python interpreter selection always visible. It used to function perfectly, and I could view model graph visualisation, etc., but it no longer does. I haven't made any changes. I tried reinstalling the extension, clearing cache, restarting, and experimenting with different settings, but nothing worked. It appears that the extension is not working because I see it cannot detect ref function or source definition, and there is no model graph or visualisation. I am unable to generate models from source definitions or run models via the buttons. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to narrow down to a specific activity and output. What does "unable to generate models" mean? What specifically are you doing, and what specifically happens?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the extension, but none of the features it offers work anymore or don't activate. Just to list some of their features which were working earlier are ability to view the models lineage, see the model dependencies or navigate to any model's definitions. Please refer to this for the list https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user .I see even the code highlighter works differently from how it was earlier. You can spot difference from the image I posted & the exampls in the link. I would appreciate any help in setting up this extension

Answer (score 0):

You can run the 'dbt debug' command and see if there are any issues in the environment.

If nothing helps, just create a bug in the GitHub repo for the extension - https://github.com/AltimateAI/vscode-dbt-power-user looks like it's actively developed and maintained.